# Why perl autovivification does not work for ->@* but ->@[0] does?

Tags: perl, autovivification

I may get values by slicing:

```
($x, $y, $z) =  $hash->{ key }->@[0,1,2]
```

Why I can not to write?

```
($x, $y, $z) =  $hash->{ key }->@*
```

For second expression in cases when `key` is not defined in hash I get error:

> Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A slice gets you lvalues (writable scalars) for each index specified; a list context array dereference doesn't make any lvalues.  And the general rule is that **autovivification only applies with lvalues**.

For example `->@*` will autovivify in this case:

```
push $hash->{ key }->@*, 1;
```